# Does there exist a function f:[1,+∞)⟶R with the following properties simultaneously?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Does there exist a function $f:[1,+\infty)\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with the following properties simultaneously ?

(1) $f$ is  strictly positive and decreasing on $[1,+\infty)$,

(2) $f$ has an antiderivative  $F$ such that $\lim_{n\longrightarrow‎ \infty}\left(F(n)-F(n+1)\right)=0$,

(3) The limit of $f(n)$ does not exist (or $\lim_{n\longrightarrow‎ \infty}f(n)\neq0$ or $f(n)$ is not convergent).

Comment: If the function is decreasing and bounded below (in this case by $0$ due to positivity), it admits an infimum and that infimum is its limit as the argument goes to infinity, so $(1)$ and $(3)$ can't be satisfied simultaneously.

Comment: Something is wrong in (3) . Otherwise you could just take  $f(x)=1/x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Property (1) implies that $f$ has a limit, so to satisfy property (3) we must have $\lim_{n \to 0} f(n) > 0$. But in that case property (2) cannot be satisfied.